# Type Casting in C language

Tags: c, typecast-operator

How to typecast `(u32IDLHeaderAddress + FIOL__nFEEIDLHeaderLength)` to avoid constraint violation?

Function declaration -

```
       Finit(const uint16 (*pastIDLTable)[2], uint16 u16NrOfDataset);
```

Function called -

```
      Finit((u32IDLHeaderAddress + IDLHeaderLength),
            (((*(uint32 *)(u32IDLHeaderAddress + 4) - FIOL__nFEEIDLHeaderLength)/4)));
```

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form.  We require the declarations of the variables and nonstandard types involved, and it would be much to your benefit to present the actual text of the diagnostic message you received.  This would be best presented as a [mcve], which could be quite brief, as the function body is not required, and the context of the call can be dummied up.

Comment: Do also note that "FInit" is not the same thing as "Finit".  I presume that one or the other contains a typo, but there's always a possibility that the call you present is calling a different function altogether, or that it is really a macro invocation.  Please clarify.

Comment: Is the second argument in your function `Finit` supposed to be a pointer? It looks to be an unsigned integer.

Comment: @Chirality: the expression dereferences the 'cast to pointer' value, so it is an integer of some sort that is produced.

Comment: Superficially, if you have an array `uint16 data[20][2];` and initialized it appropriately, you could call `FInit(&data[3], 5);` without incurring the wrath of the compiler.  You'd be best off avoiding the need for a cast; casts can hide real problems because they tell the compiler "I know better than you", and if you're asking this question, that's not yet an accurate claim.

Comment: @Chirality: But it is an unsigned integer in the call as well. I don't see any discrepancy there.

Comment: You *really* should be using some `struct`s here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the provided function declaration, the *first* argument cast should look as follows

```
(const uint16 (*)[2]) (u32IDLHeaderAddress + IDLHeaderLength)
```

It is the *first*  argument that seems to be producing the constraint violation, although it is hard to say without knowing the exact type of `u32IDLHeaderAddress`.

You for some reason seem to believe that it is the second one. The second argument looks fine to me - it already contains all casts it needs (although it appears to be a bit "overparenthesised").

Comment: I wouldn't term that code "overparenthesised" - it's more a "confusing mass of incomprehensible garbage with way too much stuffed into one line".  There's no reason to write code like that.  It *might* make sense when written, but come back 6 months later and it won't make sense without a lot of effort.  And what happens if that code ever needs to be maintained by someone not-so-proficient in C?